# AutoIT UIAutomation extension for C#

Tags: c#, automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

Started automating a windows application using Visual Studio with AutoIT.But facing problems with some controls and I came to know about the AutoIt UIAutomation. This is working fine in AutoIt Scite editor but how can we use this in Visual Studio 2015?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Per the comments of [this thread](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/39262-using-autoitx3-in-c/?do=findComment&comment=796749), there is not a way to include other '.au3' files in C#. They'll need to be translated to C# :(

---

I misunderstood the question... this answers how to reference AutoItX in C#

Per [this topic](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177167-using-autoitx-from-c-net/) on the [AutoIt Forums](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/) ...

> - Add a reference to AutoItX3.Assembly.dll to your project
> - Add a `using AutoIt;` statement in the files you want to use AutoIt functions

The AutoItX3.Assembly.dll is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX in a 'normal' installation